# How to exit spec after 10 secs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

So ive got the following code and would like to iterate it as long as 10 seconds and call done() if 10 secs reaches. i tried to add a counter and when counter === 10 call done() but that does work for me

```
it('should wait for data', function check(done) {
  newBrowser.sleep(500);
  preopPtInfoPageBrow2.getHistoryNotes().then(function(_notes) {
   (_notes !== '')? done() : check(done);
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: are you also checking if element is present?

Comment: i am not checking, the way i id like to it to work is invoke itself the function check(done) 20 times and call done() when 1) condition is met 2) 20x functions invoked